# php TCP socket read

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I get the sample code for PHP socket client and try out.
Is there a way to continue loop socket_read and pass the receive message to a local variable or even session continuously, so another php can show it?

```
while (true) {
    $out = socket_read($socket, 2048);
    echo $out;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you create the session and connect socket. Then, read socket and save value in session.

```
session_start();
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");
  while (true) {
     $result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
     $_SESSION["result"]=$result;
  }
```

Comment: this result already tried, but the result wont show up in session immediately after socket_read, instead it will wait till the connection closed then pass in the result. is there another way or better solution? I am trying to build a TCP chat program using php socket.

Comment: Try to run wireshark and double check that the data is actually sent. socket_read() with PHP_BINARY_READ should return once it is able to fetch at least 1 byte of data from the TCP stream.

Comment: Data has actually send, as i can use telnet to connect to it.
you can try as info below:
address: pkuxkx.net
port: 8080